# TYPO3 Update 7.6.47 ELTS to 7.6.48 ELTS backend-login error

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

From TYPO3 7.6.47 ELTS to 7.6.48 ELTS I get the following error when I try to log into the TYPO3 backend:

```
Core: Error handler (BE): PHP Warning: require_once(...../typo3/sysext/backend/Classes/View/PageLayout/Extdirect/ExtdirectPageCommands.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in ......./typo3_src-7.6.48/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Utility/GeneralUtility.php line 4888
```

Does anyone have a tip why this is?

Comment: try to log in the install tool and remove all cache.

Comment: I did that. I even completely removed the typo3temp folder. The problem remains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a regression in 7.6.48, please update to 7.6.49.